# Adding #ajax to checkboxes and getting selected values in callback

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I've been trying to use #ajax callbacks on a form. I've got this working with radio buttons, so when I've debugged the form I get the value associated with the radio button as '#value' under 'triggering_element' in $form_state; what I'm struggling with is doing the same thing with a group of checkboxes. The first checkbox checked seems to work correctly, and I can see the correct value, but if I click a second checkbox, the value doesn't come through correctly (triggering element is the field that was returned in the previous #ajax callback for some reason??) and '#value' is a string and not an array as I would have expected. Also $form_state['#values'] doesn't contain the previously selected checkbox or the current checkbox.

How do you correctly add #ajax to an element  of type 'checkboxes' and how is it possible to get the value of all checked checkboxes when the ajax callback is fired?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a module that can trigger an ajax callback on a form (content type) maybe that modules solves your issue http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields.

Comment: Thanks, I came across this module, but unfortunately it just uses javascript to hide fields and not load them via AJAX. I think this means that if a required field is hidden, the form won't submit unless it has been filled in. If all fields are set to not required, but really they need to be, a custom submit function would need to be created to check for this. Another issues is that when using #states, it's not possible to use a transition t show/hide the fields. I'm going to look into it again though incase I missed something...

Comment: After looking at the module again, it seems to meet my needs so think I'll be using it!

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may help you. This example is from Drupal Example module which is creating checkboxes through ajax. Compare your code with it and hopefully will find the culprit.

[Drupal Ajaxified Checkboxes example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_autocheckboxes/7)